# A basic sequence and series question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n- y_n)$$ both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are non-negative?

Assume that for the above series the following two are only possibilities (i.e if one possibility below does not happen then surely the other one happens)

1) The series $\sum z_n$ converges

2) $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of sequence of the partial sums of the series $z_n$ is $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively.

Then is it true that both of the series $\sum x_n$ and $\sum y_n$ converges ?

Comment: Is it given that $\sum z_n$ converges or diverges?

Comment: This question is quite unclear. It seems to be missing information.

Comment: @Moron: But, that is equivalent of saying 1) or 2). Clearly 3) can't happen here. So, either of 1) or 2) should happen. A book also says that 2) also can't happen. I don't understand why ?

Comment: So 1,2 -> not 3; 2,3 -> not 1; 1,3 -> not 2...and from those 3 statements, we are to infer which of 1, 2 and 3 is/are true?

Comment: When you write "the series $\{x_n\}$ converges", do you mean "the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges"? or do you mean "the series $\sum x_n$ converges"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry for creating confusion. I have edited the question.

Comment: It seems that neither 1) nor 2) guarantees convergence of the $x$ and the $y$ series, and I bet you can find examples without too much trouble.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: yes, true.